# How to set child parameter in FactoryGirl 3.3 for has_many association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2, factory-bot

There are user and user_level in our rails app. User has_many user_levels. We build FactoryGirl data set as following:

```
  factory :user_level do 
    position             "admin"
    user
  end

  factory :user do 
    login                 'testuser'
    password              "password1"

    #user_levels
    after(:build) do |user|
      user.user_levels << FactoryGirl.build(:user_level, :user => user)
    end
  end
```

The question is how to reset the position in user_level, for example, to sales? The following did not work:

```
  ul = FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:user_level, :position => 'admin')
  user = FactoryGirl.create(:user, :login => 'test', :password => 'password', 
                            :user_levels => ul)
```

The error is "undefined method 'each'". Replacing `attributes_for` with `build` generates the same error. what's the right way to reset position in user_level for the factory? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your error has nothing to do with FactoryGirl but with pure rails. You're adding a single model instance to a :has_many relation, which should be fed by an array, so try:

```
ul = FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:user_level, :position => 'admin')
user = FactoryGirl.create(:user, :login => 'test', :password => 'password', 
                        :user_levels => [ul])
```

Comment: It solved the error of undefined method 'each'. For attributes_for, there is error of AssociationMisMatch.  For build, there is no code error. However it says that the email was duplicate (but there is no user record in the table except the one being created). If removing :user_levels => [ul], there is no error with rspec.

Comment: Just rails consoled, it seems that the :user_levels => [ul] added one more user_level to the user created, in addition to the default one defined in factory. weird, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to reset child parameters in user level.

1. Added 2nd user level (or more) with reset parameters while keeping the default user_level defined in after(:build) callback.

FactoryGirl as following:

```
  factory :user_level do 
    position             "admin"
    user_id               1
  end

  factory :user do 
    login                 'testuser'
    password              "password1"

    #user_levels
    after(:build) do |user|
      user.user_levels << FactoryGirl.build(:user_level, :user => user)
    end
  end

ul = FactoryGirl.build(:user_level, :position => 'sales')
user = FactoryGirl.create(:user, :user_levels => [ul])
```

The above created user will have two positions, one is 'admin' as default, the 2nd one is position of 'sales' which is the one with reset position value.

1. user_level needs to be fed into the user creation. All user_level parameters are available for reset.

FactoryGirl as following (without callback in user):

```
  factory :user_level do 
    position             "admin"
    user_id               1
  end

  factory :user do 
    login                 'testuser'
    password              "password1"
  end

ul = FactoryGirl.build(:user_level, :position => 'sales')
user = FactoryGirl.create(:user, :user_levels => [ul])
```

The above created user will have only one position 'sales'. You are free to add more user levels to the user creation as needed.